# Suppose functions $f(\textbf{x})$ and $g(\textbf{x})$ are differentiable at $\textbf{x}_0$, show that their product $fg$ is differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Suppose real valued functions $f(\textbf{x})$ and $g(\textbf{x})$ are differentiable at $\textbf{x}_0$, show that their product $fg$ is differentiable at $\textbf{x}_0$ and prove that $f(\textbf{x}_0)dg(\textbf{x}_0)+g(\textbf{x}_0)df(\textbf{x}_0)=d(fg)(\textbf{x}_0)$.

For differentiability of a function a real vaued function $f$ at $\textbf{x}_0$, we require:
$$\lim_{|\textbf{h}| \to 0} \frac{f(\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{h})-f(\textbf{x}_0)-df(\textbf{x}_0) \cdot \textbf{h}}{|\textbf{h}|}=0$$
where $df(\textbf{x}_0)$ is a covector.

My proof is very similar to that of the sinlge variable case, but I get stuck at the very last step.

---

We wish to show that
$$\lim_{|\textbf{h}| \to 0} \frac{f(\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{h})g(\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{h})-f(\textbf{x}_0)g(\textbf{x}_0)-d(fg)(\textbf{x}_0) \cdot \textbf{h}}{|\textbf{h}|}=0$$
Now,
\begin{align}
\lim_{\textbf{|h|} \to 0} \frac{f(\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{h})g(\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{h})-f(\textbf{x}_0)g(\textbf{x}_0)-d(fg)(\textbf{x}_0) \cdot \textbf{h}}{|\textbf{h}|}&=\lim_{\textbf{|h|} \to 0} \frac{f(\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{h})g(\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{h})-(g(\textbf{x}_0 + \textbf{h})f+dg(\textbf{x}_0) \cdot \textbf{h})+(g(\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{h})f+dg(\textbf{x}_0) \cdot \textbf{h})-f(\textbf{x}_0)g(\textbf{x}_0)-d(fg)(\textbf{x}_0) \cdot \textbf{h}}{|\textbf{h}|} \\
&= \lim_{\textbf{|h|} \to 0} \left( \frac{f(\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{h})-f(\textbf{x}_0)-df(\textbf{x}_0) \cdot \textbf{h}}{|\textbf{h}|} \right)g(\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{h}) + \lim_{\textbf{|h|} \to 0} \left( \frac{g(\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{h})-g(\textbf{x}_0) - dg(\textbf{x}_0) \cdot \textbf{h}}{|\textbf{h}|} \right)f(\textbf{x}_0)\\
&+ \lim_{\textbf{|h|} \to 0} \left( \frac{f(\textbf{x}_0)dg(\textbf{x}_0) \cdot \textbf{h}+g(\text{x}_0+\textbf{h})dg(\textbf{x}_0) \cdot \textbf{h} - d(fg)(\textbf{x}_0) \cdot \textbf{h}}{|\textbf{h}|} \right)
\end{align}
By the differentiability of $f$ and $g$ at $\textbf{x}_0$, we have that
\begin{align}
\lim_{\textbf{|h|} \to 0} \frac{f(\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{h})g(\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{h})-f(\textbf{x}_0)g(\textbf{x}_0)-d(fg)(\textbf{x}_0) \cdot \textbf{h}}{|\textbf{h}|} 
&=\lim_{\textbf{|h|} \to 0} \frac{1}{|\textbf{h}|} \textbf{h} \cdot \left( {f(\textbf{x}_0)dg(\textbf{x}_0)+g(\textbf{x}_0+\textbf{h})dg(\textbf{x}_0) - d(fg)(\textbf{x}_0) } \right)
\end{align}
Clearly, this is very close to the result, but I'm not sure where to go from here. My intuition to consider the unit vector of $\textbf{h}$. But again, I'm unsure.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should state more about the functions $f$ and $g$, such as their domain

Comment: @Victor nothing was stated about that in the question, simply differentiability.

Comment: You can insert what suspect to be the derivative of $fg$. The definition reads: $fg$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if there exists a covector, label it $d(fg)(x_0)$, such that the limit above exists. If you show that what you wrote in the first paragraph does the job, then you're finished. From there you should see which terms you have to add and subtract. Note that hereby happens nothing new compared to the one-dimensional case, up to some notations.

Comment: @nicrot000 So I simply state that for the covector $d(fg)(\textbf{x}_0)=f(\textbf{x}_0)dg(\textbf{x}_0)+g(\textbf{x}_0)df(\textbf{x}_0)$ makes the limit zero in the last line, and we are done (?)

Comment: Note that in a small neighbourhood of $x_0$ you have $\|g(x_0+h)-g(x_0)\| \le K \|h\|$ for some $K$.

Comment: @copper.hat could you further elaborate how this is supposed to help? (Also, I thought that result only held for convex sets)

Comment: The result follows from differentiability at $x_0$.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But note that a rigorous justification for your computation is then somewhat bottom to top, meaning that each step is justified by the existence of the limit you arrive at. In the end, you'll arrive at a limit of which you know that it is zero, justifying the step before, justifying the step before, and so on. Or you choose a more elegant forward argumentation in order to estimate the expression whose limit you wish to exist, but still, as in my first comment, you have to insert what you suspect to be the derivative (using the estimates which @copper.hat suggests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, just too long for a comment:

I am assuming $x_0=0$ just to reduce typing below.

$f(h)g(h)-f(0)g(h)+f(0)g(h)-f(0)g(0)- Df(0)h g(0)-f(0)Dg(0)h$

equals

$f(0)( g(h)-g(0)-Dg(0)h) + (f(h)-f(0)-Df(0)h)g(h) + Df(0)h(g(h)-g(0))$

$g$ is continuous at $0$ so is bounded in a neighourhood.

$g$ is differentiable at $0$ so
$\|g(h)-g(0)\| \le K \|h\|$ for some $K$ and $h$ in some
neighbourhood of $0$.

To see the latter, note that for some neighbourhood of $0$ you have
$\|g(h)-g(0)-Dg(0)h\| \le \epsilon \|h\|$ and so
$\|g(h)-g(0)\| \le (\epsilon + \|Dg(0)\|) \|h\|$, setting $K=\epsilon + \|Dg(0)\|$ does the trick.

Comment: Thank you! Looks good